# RxJava linear backoff, passing in earlier date parameters on retry

Tags: android, retrofit, rx-java, rx-android, retrofit2

I'm refactoring some code that would call a web service with a formatted date parameter ("2016-3-10" for example), and if that returned null, would fire off another method with a date one day earlier (like "2016-3-9"). This would happen for at least 3 retries.

I'm refactoring this into RxJava and am not sure how to implement the backoff strategy or which `.retry()` or `.retryWhen()` operator to use in this situation.

I have the web service returning the usual `Observable` using Retrofit.

This is what I have currently:

```
 PictureService pictureService = retrofit.create(PictureService.class);

        pictureService.getPhotos(date)
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .retry() //Some retry

                ...
                .subscribe()
```

So which operator would be best used here for retrying the requests, and how should I pass in a new date to the `getPhotos()` request when the current date returns null?

Just for the sake of completion here is the Retrofit service that was mentioned above:

```
@GET("/someurl/photos?api_key=xxxxxxx")
Observable<PictureAPI> getPhotos(@Query("earth_date") String earthDate);
```

Comment: I disagree that this is a duplicate, as I'm not implementing any backoff strategy utilizing timing. I would like to know how to implement the logic for retrying when the response returns null.

Comment: I also don't think this is a duplicate. @Orbit: I don't think the `retry` family will get you anywhere here. 1.) They usually kick in when on `onError` comes down the chain. You could transform any `null`s to errors and then `retry` but 2) you actually don't want to retry at all: You want a different Observable if the first one fails... But, now that I am writing this, I have an idea... stay tuned!

Comment: Oh, damn, I can't answer this anymore, since it's supposedly a duplicate... Well... Look here: http://blog.danlew.net/2015/06/22/loading-data-from-multiple-sources-with-rxjava/ And then think of this `Observable.just("2016-3-10", "2016-3-9", "2016-3-8").flatMap(date -> pictureService.getPhotos(date)).filter(response -> response != null).take(1)...`

Comment: I guess that *could* work, but would make 3 requests initially and then filter afterwards, which isn't too pretty. Will try it out and keep looking, thanks!

Comment: Ah yes, had to run to a meeting and of course I messed it up... You need `concatMap` instead of `flatMap`. This will make sure that each Observable is only subscribed to when the previous proved inadeqate... As Dan explains in his blog post: `concat` (and `concatMap`) will subscribe to each new Observable only after the previous one has emitted `onCompleted` AND only if more items are needed downstream. The `take(1)` will unsubscribe after the first non-`null` response and therefore `concatMap` will just not subscriber to the next Observable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, now that I can answer this question again, here we go:

```
Observable.just("2016-3-10", "2016-3-9", "2016-3-8")
.concatMap(date -> pictureService.getPhotos(date))
.filter(response -> response != null)
.take(1)...
```

For a detailed explanation take a look at this blog post by Dan Lew: http://blog.danlew.net/2015/06/22/loading-data-from-multiple-sources-with-rxjava/

In short: `concat` (and `concatMap`) will subscribe to each new `Observable` only after the previous one has emitted `onCompleted` AND only if more items are needed downstream. The `take(1)` will unsubscribe after the first non-`null` response and therefore `concatMap` will just not subscribe to the next `Observable`.

**EDIT:** To check that really only one request is sent you could

1.) Enable logging in Retrofit (if you are recent version by adding an `Interceptor` to the `OkHttpClient`). This lets you directly observe the requests that are being sent.

2.) Add a `doOnSubscribe()` like this:

```
.concatMap(date -> pictureService.getPhotos(date)
    .doOnSubscribe(new Action0() {
        @Override
        public void call() {
            Log.d(TAG, "sending request for " + date);   
        }
    });
)
```

Since Retrofit requests are only sent upon subscription the log message will appear if and only if a request is then sent.

Comment: Is there a simple way to test that only one call is going out?